# Archivo NO descarga en proyecto laravel estando en producción

Tags: php, laravel, servidor, almacenamiento

Al intentar subir un aplicativo web desarrollado en laravel 5.1 al servidor local ...aparece el siguiente error al intentar descargar un archivo:

**LogicException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 135:
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)**

ya descomente **la extensión fileinfo** del php.ini, ademas ya le di **todos los permisos** a las carpetas afines a la descarga del archivo, pero aun así no se soluciona el error...

Aquí los códigos sospechosos:

CONTROLADOR:

```
 public function downloadFile($file)
{
    $public_path = public_path();
    $url = $public_path.'/bitacora/'. $file;
    //verificamos si el archivo existe y lo retornamos
    if (Storage::exists($file))
    {
        return response()->download($url)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
    //si no se encuentra lanzamos un error 404.
    abort(404);

}
```

MODELO:

```
class Bitacora extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'archivos';
   protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombre_archivo', 'nombre_usuario', 'path'];

   public function setPathAttribute($path)
   {
       $this->attributes['path'] = Carbon::now()->
       second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
       $archi = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
       \Storage::disk('local')->put($archi, \File::get($path));
   }
 }
```

FILESYSTEMS.PHP

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path('bitacora'),
    ],
```

Vale aclarar que estoy trabajando con un windows server 2012 administrado con el **IIS**.

Comment: Después de modificar el archivo `php.ini`, reiniciaste el servidor?

Comment: SI, de inmediato...pero nada

Comment: Podrías mostrar como seria la ruta que que se genera del la concatene de  public_path.'/bitacora/'. $file;  de un archivo de ejemplo

Comment: "VARIABLE $URL: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranetcercafe\public/bitacora/42vvcv.txt" y "$PUBLIC_PATH: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranetcercafe\public"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal a todos... Pude solucionar este problema al observar que el Administrador del IIS de **WINDOWS SERVER** tiene **oculto** un Archivo **php.ini** en un ítem denominado **PHP MANAGER**. Solo consistió en colocar la extensión y listo... muchas gracias. Vale aclarar que antes había modificado los **.ini** del servidor local, mas no el del **administrador IIS**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es este:

```
        return Response::download($url);
```

Depende de la versión de laravel que uses sera distinto, pero prueba:

```
return response()->download($url)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: El proyecto esta desarrollado en laravel 5.1, ya probé el return pero sigue igual... Pero en si el return que usted dice si corresponde al de la versión 5.1...muchas gracias por la observación...

Comment: Mírate esto sino: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051722/laravel-file-download-php-fileinfo-extension-not-enabled